# how to find all launch configuration name which has a common name prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to find all launch configuration names which has a text in launch config name.

For eg: Say there are 3 launch config name 'awsLC1' 'xyzLC2' 'aLC3' 'pqrst'

I want a query where it fetches me 3 launch configurations using aws CLI.

I tried to wrote following query using JMESpath, but it didn't work out since LaunchConfigurtionName is not an array.

```
 aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations --query LaunchConfigurations[? LaunchConfigurationName [? contains(@,'LC')]].LaunchConfigurationName" --output text
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply change contains() to evaluate the field you want to check, instead of using the `@` array syntax. From the contains() documentation:

> boolean contains(array|string $subject, any $search)
>
> If the provided $subject is a string, this function returns true if the string contains the provided $search argument.

### Example to find launch configuration names containing 'LC':

```
contains(LaunchConfigurationName,'LC')
```

### Full Example:

```
aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations --query "LaunchConfigurations[?contains(LaunchConfigurationName,'LC')].LaunchConfigurationName" --output text
```

### Further Reading:

- [JMESPath Documentation - Contains()](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains)

Comment: Thanks It worked. I was trying JMESPath only but was applying incorrect syntax earlier.